Scala how to prevent empty lines in scala interpolated string template?
I have an object with some optional attributes which I want to list in a string template (In a sort of JSON way) If the attribute is None I don't want to see anything, if it is Non None I want to see a label with the value:
case class FooTest(a: String, b: Option[String], c: String)
val test = FooTest("one", Some("two"), "three");

val myTemplate = s"""
| "een" : "${test.a}"
| ${test.b.fold(""){tb => s"\"twee\": \"$tb\"}
| "drie" : "${test.c}"
"""

This works expected with Some("value") for test.b, but it leaves a blank line for
None for test.b:
"een" : "one"

"drie" : "three"

How can I get rid of the empty line (apart from replacing 2 subsequent newline characters with 1 newline in the resulting string)?

I would expect something like paiges: https://github.com/typelevel/paiges to provide a better way to solve this problem.

Depends on how pervasive this kind of pretty printing is. Dependencies are not free. I would probably use string templates for a handful of occasions, implement a simple pretty printer if it pops up more often than that and consider adding a dependency if it’s pervasive, I don’t have the resources to write it on my own, and have specific requirements that make that dependency fit for adoption in my project.

One possibility might be to inline the second line and explicitly add the newline, which kinda works but doesn't interact too nicely with indentation:
case class FooTest(a: String, b: Option[String], c: String)

def template(test: FooTest) = s"""
| "een" : "${test.a}"${test.b.fold(""){tb => s"\n\"twee\": \"$tb\""}}
| "drie" : "${test.c}"
""".stripMargin

println(template(FooTest("one", Some("two"), "three")))
println(template(FooTest("one", None, "three")))

Output:
 "een" : "one"
"twee": "two"
 "drie" : "three"


 "een" : "one"
 "drie" : "three"

If you want to keep the template string nice and work well with the template indentation, one possible approach is to remove the empty lines in a second pass, as follows:
case class FooTest(a: String, b: Option[String], c: String)

def template(test: FooTest) = s"""
| "een" : "${test.a}"
| ${test.b.fold(""){tb => s"\"twee\": \"$tb\""}}
| "drie" : "${test.c}"
""".stripMargin

def deleteEmptyLines(s: String) = s.replaceAll("\\n\\s*\\n", "\n")

println(deleteEmptyLines(template(FooTest("one", Some("two"), "three"))))
println(deleteEmptyLines(template(FooTest("one", None, "three"))))

Output:
 "een" : "one"
 "twee": "two"
 "drie" : "three"


 "een" : "one"
 "drie" : "three"

You can play around with this code here on Scastie.
